# how to add commas for every listed item

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, text-processing

in my shell program i just cut the names in the server and display them,

```
echo `last | grep "pts" | sort | cut -d' ' -f1 | uniq |  grep -v / `"."
```

gives me an output of

```
a22casti 
a22sahot 
a25zhang 
a298wong 
a2abdiri 
a2arya 
a2mukhop 
a3vena.
```

how can i make it add commas so its

```
a22casti,
a22sahot,
a25zhang,
a298wong,
a2abdiri,
a2arya,
a2mukhop,
a3vena.
```

i tried adding `tr '\n' ','` but it would add a comma at the end of the sentence
`a3vena,.`

Comment: If your output is `a22casti a22sahot a25zhang a298wong a2abdiri a2arya a2mukhop a3vena.` with a _blank_ between the words than `tr " " ","` should work.

Comment: sorry thats when its echoed, its actually listed vertically

Comment: Have you tried `tr '\n\n' ',\n'`?

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a comma to the end of every line, and on the last line remove it:

```
sed -e 's/$/,/' -e '$s/,$//'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
paste -sd, -
```

will give you the desired output. Or try the `sed` version:

In the pipeline after the `grep` add the following:

```
sed -Ez 'y/\n/,/;s/,$//'
```

This assumes you have gnu sed and you are operating it in the slurp mode `-z` and extended regex mode `-E`. First we change all newlines to comma and then remove the last comma.

Comment: `-z` is not _slurp mode_, it's the NUL-delimited-record mode.